# CoreData: Use of MagicalRecord with FetchedResultsController and a custom sortDescriptor

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I've just started using the [MagicalRecord library](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord) to make it easier to work with CoreData. I'm using an FRC and can't figure out how to set it up with a custom sortDescriptor such as

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                        initWithKey:@"someAttribute"
                          ascending:YES
                           selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Currently my call to retrieve the FRC is as such:

```
_fetchedResultsController = [Language MR_fetchAllSortedBy:@"someAttribute"
                                                ascending:YES
                                            withPredicate:nil
                                                  groupBy:nil
                                                 delegate:self];
```

It seems like what I'm looking for is a way to "simply" add a **custom selector** to MR_fetchAllSortedBy. Something like:

```
_fetchedResultsController = 
       [Language MR_fetchAllSortedBy:@"someAttribute"
                           ascending:YES
                            selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)
                       withPredicate:nil
                             groupBy:nil
                            delegate:self];
```

Could anyone give me some pointers on how to achieve this? With the use of a Category maybe?

Thanks in advance,

Joss.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem today. You can't set a custom sort descriptor through the MR_FindAll methods but you can create your own fetch request whilst still leveraging Magical Records boilerplate code:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [Sites MR_createFetchRequest];
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]];

self.sitesArray = [NSManagedObject MR_executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest];
```