# Case Insensitive Compare with Magical Record library(Core Data) and Swift

Tags: swift, core-data, magicalrecord

Is it possible to add sortDescriptor in MagicalRecord request to get case insensitive sorting

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Case Insensitive Compare with Core Data and Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35165986/case-insensitive-compare-with-core-data-and-swift)

Comment: Nope, I use MagicalRecord to work with coreData and I can't add sortDescriptors

Comment: From what I recall (I used it 10 years ago), you could add sort descriptors. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14216022/coredata-use-of-magicalrecord-with-fetchedresultscontroller-and-a-custom-sortde What's your request call?

Comment: @Larme Yes! Create my own fetchRequest helped. Thanks!

Comment: Note that the library hasn't been updated for a long time and on the project page it says _"This project's activity has stopped, superseded by Core Data itself"_ so maybe the best solution here is to not use the library and work with Core Data directly.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thanks, I take it into account. May be there are some other libraries that you can recommend

Comment: Why do you need a 3rd party library at all?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, just to make easier work with CoreData